# How to abandon changes in some directories using git?

Tags: git

I have a little complicated question related to abandoning modified files in git.
My project structure is following:

```
-root
   -web
   -backend
```

1. I made a new branch let's call it "newfeature" from master and I started modifying files in **backend** folder.
2. In meantime on the master, changes were done in folder **web**.
3. I pulled from master and then made a merge from master into newbranch. All changes from web folder were added to my **newfeature** branch.
4. I added all files to commit and pushed it to remote branch **newfeature**
5. I made few more commits under backand folder.

Now I realized that I do not bother about changes in other folders than backand and I want to unlink this directories to avoid merges.

How to unlink that dictionary from branch?

Comment: Do you want to not track web directory in your local or do you want to separate it for everyone?

Comment: I do not want tracking changes under this folder localy and remotly. I made a pull request from this branch and now changes under web folder are visible in this pull request. That pull request has been made to modify files under **backend folder only.**

Comment: Sorry for typo in last comment, refresh page please.

Comment: Ah okay, so you just want to remove web folder changes from your pull request, one time only? If you want to split two directories, you have to have 2 repositories or you have to use git sub repositories

Comment: so you just want to remove web folder changes from your pull request, one time only?
Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to clean up your pull request:

```
git rebase -i
```

Using interactive rebase, you'll be able to change the git history of a branch [more about it here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).
Then you'll be promted with your changes:

```
- commit1
- commit2
- merge of web
- commit
```

In each line you can choose to edit, pick etc. If you delete your merge commit with web changes, your branch will get rid of that merge action. So your pull request can be cleaned. Just follow the instructions to complete rebase

After that you have to push with -f (force) to change remote history of your feature branch

```
git push -f
```